# get the href link in table columns in python with -beautiful-soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this data as you can see :

```
[<td><span></span></td>, <td><span></span></td>, <td><a class="cmc-link" href="/currencies/renbtc/"><span class="circle"></span><span>renBTC</span><span class="crypto-symbol">RENBTC</span></a></td>, <td><span>$<!-- -->61947.68</span></td>, <td><span></span></td>]
```

I want to extract the `href` link as you can see here is `/currencies/renbtc/`.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
try:
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    
    table = soup.find('table', class_='cmc-table')
    for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):    
        # Find all data for each column
         columns = row.find_all('td')
         print(columns)
         
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```

but the result is the whole columns .

Comment: use `.get('href')` on that anchor tag object

Comment: @Matiiss  print(columns.get('href')) RETURN ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operate on the element from columns that holds the `<a>`, select it and get its `href`:

```
link = columns[2].a['href']
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
try:
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    
    table = soup.find('table', class_='cmc-table')
    for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):    
        # Find all data for each column
         columns = row.find_all('td')
         link = columns[2].a['href']
         print(link)
         
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the `<td>` in the list and if that `<td>` has `<a>` (`if td.a`), then `.get('href')` of `td.a`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
try:
    r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('table', class_='cmc-table')

    for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
        # Find all data for each column
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        for td in columns:
            if td.a:
                print(td.a.get('href'))
                # theoretically for performance you can
                # break
                # here to stop the loop if you expect only one anchor link per `td`

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
```